# Как разрешить передачу сериализуемого класса между доменами приложения?

Tags: .net, appdomain, msbuild

Вот такой код работает:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("secondary");
        var executor = (Executor)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(Program).Assembly.FullName, typeof(Executor).FullName);
        executor.Run(new Message { content = "Hello, world!" });
    }

    [Serializable]
    class Message
    {
        public string content;
    }

    class Executor : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public void Run(Message message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message.content);
            Console.WriteLine("Domain: {0}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
        }
    }
}
```

Но то же самое, сделанное из задачи `MSBuild`, приводит к ошибке "Не разрешен тип члена ${полное имя типа Message}". В стеке вызовов ничего интересного.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Преждего всего ремарка: русский вариант текста исключения может навести на ложный след. Проблема не в разрешениях (permissions), а в резолвинге. Оригинальный текст исключения следующий: "Type is not resolved for member ...", что говорит о том, что .NET не смог найти нужный тип.

---

По умолчанию аппдомен пытается резолвить сборки в той же папке, откуда запущен процесс, который этот аппдомен породил. В случае запуска консольного приложения -- нужная сборка там конечно же лежит. В случае с запуском из-под MSBuild -- это директория MSBuild'а, и ваша сборка не находится. В этом можно убедиться, запустив Fuslogvw.exe и посмотрев, где домен пытается резолвить сборку.

При создании аппдомена задавайте явно путь к вашим сборкам:

```
AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup()
{
    ApplicationBase = ...
    // остальные опции по желанию
}

var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("secondary", null, setup);
```

P.S. И еще мне почему-то кажется, что `Message` тоже надо наследовать от `MarshalByRefObject`...

Comment: Отмечу, что ошибка возникает именно при вызове `executor.Run` - если бы сборка и правда не нашлась, то программа упала бы строкой раньше.

Comment: А наследование `Message` от `MarshalByRefObject` - это лучший способ убить производительность! Я затем и пытаюсь создать сериализуемый тип, чтобы передать все нужные мне параметры за раз - вы же предлагаете делать кроссдоменный запрос каждый раз, когда захочется прочитать или установить значение поля.

Comment: PS на всякий случай запустил вашу программу. Сборка ищется именно там, где и лежит.

Comment: @PavelMayorov тогда другой вопрос: версия .NET, под которую собрана ваша сборка, отличается от версии, под которую собран MSBuild? Если да, попробуйте собрать ее под версию MSBuild'а.